# Using a jsp as an img src in liferay portlet

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet

I have some code that checks an xml node value and displays an image if the value is `true`:

```
<x:if select="$person/pictureprivate != 'false'">
    <c:set var="pidm">
        <x:out select="$person/@pidm" />
    </c:set>
    <img src="<%=renderRequest.getContextPath()%>/getPicture.jsp&amp;pidm=${pidm}"></img>
</x:if>
```

The jsp that is the source is a post to a webservice:

```
int len;
int size = 1024;
byte[] buf;
OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
String pidm=request.getParameter("pidm");

//out.print("URL: " + urlProp + pidm);
URL url = new URL("myURL" + pidm);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

connection.setDoOutput(true);

connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
connection.setReadTimeout(5000);

InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();


 if (is instanceof ByteArrayInputStream) {
  size = is.available();
  buf = new byte[size];
  len = is.read(buf, 0, size);
} 
else {
  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  buf = new byte[size];
  while ((len = is.read(buf, 0, size)) != -1)
    bos.write(buf, 0, len);
  buf = bos.toByteArray();
}

 o.write(buf);  
 o.flush();
 o.close();
```

I know the webservice jsp works, because I use it in another application. However, the image doesn't load in my liferay portlet, and trying to `right click -> view image results` in the apache error `the requested resource is not available`. I'm thinking I might be defining my src path wrong but I'm not sure.

Comment: What does renderRequest.getContextPath() resolve to ? Is your jsp on that path relative to your web application root ?

Comment: Did you really mean `...getPicture.jsp&amp;pidm=...`? I suppose it should be `...getPicture.jsp?pidm=...`.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke That was correct. I fixed that problem.

Answer (score 1):

`renderRequest`'s `getContextPath` most likely resolves to the portal's context, while your plugin has its own context. In fact, even `request.getContextPath` most likely resolves to the portal (but please double check it): When a portlet is served, the request is handled by the portal. When you want to address a resource from your portlet's webcontext, you'll need to explicitly address it and either hard-code the web context of your portlet (inelegant) or find how to address it.

Follow @ramp's comment and check what `getContextPath` (for both `renderRequest` and `request`) actually resolves to and you're closer to the solution. If in doubt, just replace it with the hardcoded context path for now and continue to search for the dynamic path.

Also note that you won't have any access to the portal's signed in user account in your JSP if requested in the way that you want to. You're not making any use of it in the JSP, so it should be fine - but I just wanted to make sure that this is understood as well